# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 422

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm using volley library to register user to backend server via POST method. But it is showing BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 422 in android logcat. any help? Also it is uploading user's data to my server too. But not giving apt response/result.

also tried by adding or removing

```
params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        params.put("Accept", "application/json");
```

and

```
 headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
```

here is my code

```
 private void register() {

    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);

    final String email = "" + inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = "" + inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String address = "" + inputAddress.getText().toString().trim();
    final String phone = "" + inputPhone.getText().toString().trim();
    final String gender = "" + spnGender.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    final String bloodgroup = "" + spnBloodGroup.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    final String name = "" + inputName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String role = "user";
    final String status = "true";


    mDialog.setTitle("Authenticating..");
    mDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("RESULT", response.toString());
                    mDialog.hide();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("RESULT", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            // hide the progress dialog
            mDialog.hide();
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("ERROR RESPONSE", "result= " + error);

            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Connection timeout, please try after sometime..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                //TODO
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                //TODO
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                //TODO
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    //TODO
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Server Busy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");

            params.put("phone", phone);
            params.put("address", address);
            params.put("gender", gender);
            params.put("bloodgroup", bloodgroup);
            params.put("role", role);
            params.put("username", name);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("status", status);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code with @Override

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();



        params.put("phone", phone);
        params.put("address", address);
        params.put("gender", gender);
        params.put("bloodgroup", bloodgroup);
        params.put("role", role);
        params.put("username", name);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("status", status);
        return params;
    }
```

422 means request body is not correct.

Thanks.

Comment: you want me to remove @override?

Comment: Not override, but params

Comment: I removed json ones

Comment: Tried but not working, i've also mentioned that i tried by adding or removing params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        params.put("Accept", "application/json");